# set alarm with multiple pending intent not pass the event to broadcast

Tags: android

On satat command service i want to ser multiple pending intents to broadcast on particular time in a day so i use multiple alarm manager is it correct or wrong way please suggest me.

```
 @Override
            public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Traffic Control BK Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d(TAG, "onStart");  

            Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date date1 = calendar1.getTime();

            calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date date2 = calendar2.getTime();

            calendar3 = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date date3 = calendar3.getTime();

            calendar4 = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date date4 = calendar4.getTime();

            calendar5 = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date date5 = calendar5.getTime();

            calendar6 = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date date6 = calendar6.getTime();

            calendar7 = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date date7 = calendar7.getTime();

            calendar8 = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date date8 = calendar8.getTime();

            calendar9 = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date date9 = calendar9.getTime();
            //int x=0;
            if(tg111.charAt(0)=='1'){

                //calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, date1.getDate());
                calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 3);
                calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
                calendar1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

                i1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Trafficc.class);
                pi1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, i1, 0);
                am1 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                am1.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar1.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi1);

            }

            if(tg111.charAt(1)=='1'){

                    //calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calendar2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, date2.getDate());
                    calendar2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 4);
                    calendar2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
                    calendar2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);


                    i2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Trafficc.class);
                    pi2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 1, i1, 0);
                    am2 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                    am2.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar2.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi2);
            }

            if(tg111.charAt(2)=='1'){
                //calendar3 = Calendar.getInstance();

                calendar3.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,date3.getDate());
                calendar3.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 5);
                calendar3.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 45);
                calendar3.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);


            i3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Trafficc.class);
            pi3 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, i3, 0);
            am3 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            am3.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar3.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi3);


            }

            if(tg111.charAt(3)=='1'){

                //calendar4 = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar4.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,date4.getDate());
                calendar4.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 7);
                calendar4.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
                calendar4.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);


            i4 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Trafficc.class);
            pi4 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, i4, 0);
            am4 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            am4.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar4.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi4);

            }

            if(tg111.charAt(4)=='1'){

                //calendar5 = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar5.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,date5.getDate());
                calendar5.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
                calendar5.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
                calendar5.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);


            i5 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Trafficc.class);
            pi5 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, i5, 0);
            am5 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            am5.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar5.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi5);
            }

            if(tg111.charAt(5)=='1'){


               // calendar6 = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar6.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,date6.getDate());
                calendar6.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
                calendar6.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
                calendar6.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

            i6 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Trafficc.class);
            pi6 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, i6, 0);
            am6 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            am6.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar6.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi6);


            }

            if(tg111.charAt(6)=='1'){

                //calendar7 = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar7.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,date7.getDate());
                calendar7.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
                calendar7.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
                calendar7.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);


            i7 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Trafficc.class);
            pi7 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, i7, 0);
            am7 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            am7.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar7.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi7);
            }

            if(tg111.charAt(7)=='1'){

                //calendar8 = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar8.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,date8.getDate());
                calendar8.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19);
                calendar8.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
                calendar8.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);


            i8 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Trafficc.class);
            pi8 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, i8, 0);
            am8 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            am8.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar8.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi8);

            }

            if(tg111.charAt(8)=='1'){

                //calendar9 = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar9.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,date9.getDate());
                calendar9.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
                calendar9.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
                calendar9.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

            i9 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Trafficc.class);
            pi9 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, i9, 0);
            am9 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            am9.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar9.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi9);

            }

            return START_STICKY;
            }
```

**Broadcast Receiver**

```
package com.atpl.bkapp;

import java.util.Calendar;


import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Trafficc extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         Calendar cal1= Calendar.getInstance();
         int hour = cal1.get(Calendar.HOUR);
         int min = cal1.get(Calendar.MINUTE);   


        if ((hour==3) && (min==30))
        {
            Toast.makeText(arg0, "showname-->3:30", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else if((hour==4) && (min==00))
        {
            Toast.makeText(arg0, "showname--> 4:00", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else if((hour==5) && (min==45))
        {
            Toast.makeText(arg0, "showname--> 5:45", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else if((hour==7) && (min==00))
        {
            Toast.makeText(arg0, "showname--> 7:00", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else if((hour==10) && (min==30))
        {
            Toast.makeText(arg0, "showname--> 10:30", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else if((hour==12) && (min==00))
        {
            Toast.makeText(arg0, "showname--> 12:00", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else if((hour==17) && (min==30))
        {
            Toast.makeText(arg0, "showname--> 17:30", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else if((hour==19) && (min==30))
        {
            Toast.makeText(arg0, "showname--> 19:30", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else if((hour==21) && (min==30))
        {
            Toast.makeText(arg0, "showname--> 21:30", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

}
```

Please help me solve the issue to set alarm on multiple times in a day
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

WRONG:

```
 pi1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, i1, 0);
```

RIGHT:

```
 pi1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), Counter, i1, 0);
```

here , `counter` is the identical value which will incremental every time while you check your case in `if` loop for new `PendingIntent`

A common mistake people make is to create multiple PendingIntent objects with Intents that only vary in their "extra" contents, expecting to get a different PendingIntent each time